# Error trying to coexist Python 2.7.5 and Python 3.3.2 on Windows 7

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.3, coexistence

I'm hearing the call to move my Python code from 2 to 3, so I'm trying to setup Python 3 on my Windows 7 box that already has Python 2.7.5 on it.  The python 2 version is 64 bit and so is the Python 3 version that I've most recently installed.  I am worried, however, that I might've installed and uninstalled a 32 bit version of Python 3.3.2 by accident and that remnants from it are causing the following error to be thrown when I attempt to edit my code with IDLE.

```
"The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b)."
```

I checked my registry key and this occurs when the Python 33 Idle is being used.  Additionally I tried to use Dependency Walker on it, a program I am unfamiliar with, and got the following "errors."  The system cannot find the following files.

```
API-MS-WIN-CORE-COM-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-ERROR-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-ROBUFFER-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-STRING-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SHCORE-SCALING-L1-1-0.DLL
DCOMP.DLL
IESHIMS.DLL
```

Additionally, I see that Python33.dll is x86 instead of x64.

Comment: I answered my own question as I was trying to describe it on here.  Here is the answer :

Comment: OK, so I figured out the answer to my own problem and just decided to answer it here for anyone else who ran, has run, or will run into the same problem.

So the issue is with the Python33.dll.  It seems if you install the 32bit version of Python 3 then install the 64bit version, you'll still have the 32bit version of the Python 33.dll.  I just deleted the .dll and repaired my 64bit installation of Python 3 and now the IDLE editor works correctly from the context menu.  

Who knows what other errors I have, however :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copying the answer from the comments in order to remove this question from the "Unanswered" filter:

> OK, so I figured out the answer to my own problem and just decided to
>   answer it here for anyone else who ran, has run, or will run into the
>   same problem. So the issue is with the Python33.dll. It seems if you
>   install the 32bit version of Python 3 then install the 64bit version,
>   you'll still have the 32bit version of the Python 33.dll. I just
>   deleted the .dll and repaired my 64bit installation of Python 3 and
>   now the IDLE editor works correctly from the context menu. Who knows
>   what other errors I have, however :)

~ answer per [Karsten Chu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1218689/karsten-chu)

Comment: Thanks!  Forgot to copy the comment over to the answer after the 8 hour time limit was up.

Comment: No worries. If you still want to copy your comment to an answer, I'll delete mine. Thanks!